# Mongoimport not finding file?

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoimport

```
mongoimport --uri mongodb+srv://gtye:<PASSWORD>@dxgraph.rymok.mongodb.net/dxgraph-db --collection dxgraph-collection --type json --file ~/DxHero%20Godot/Data/postgres_export.json
```

returns

```
2021-05-25T12:58:05.538-0400    Failed: open /Users/gtye/DxHero%20Godot/Data/postgres_export.json: no such file or directory
2021-05-25T12:58:05.538-0400    0 document(s) imported successfully. 0 document(s) failed to import.
```

But I know it's there!!

[image]

It's literally right here!! What the heck is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%20` is a URI escaping mechanism. It doesn't work in the shell.

Try:

```
mongoimport --uri mongodb+srv://gtye:<PASSWORD>@dxgraph.rymok.mongodb.net/dxgraph-db --collection dxgraph-collection --type json --file ~/"DxHero Godot/Data/postgres_export.json"
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! It fixed (pretty much) everything! I just had to do what you said and then add --jsonArray at the end and then it worked!